# ScrollTo: targeting specific buttons in a navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Got an issue with a navbar I'm creating for a WordPress site. Some of the links are meant to scroll down to different places on the homepage and some are outside links to other places on the site. Something like this:

```
<div class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="link1"><a href="page1.html">Link 1</a>
        <li class="link2"><a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basic stuff.

So if I add the following Javascript in the footer....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.main-navigation a' ).click(function(){
  jQuery.scrollTo( this.hash, 1000, { easing:'swing' });
  return false;
});
```

Link 2 will scroll down but since Link 1 isn't supposed to scroll, if you click on it, nothing happens like it's a null link.

I thought I could change the reference to something like

```
jQuery('.main-navigation a.link2' ).click(function(){
```

So only link 2 does the scrolling, but that just makes it jump to the page like an old anchor tag trick in the 1990's.

Tried a few variations of the same idea, and nothing clicked. Anyone know what the right code would be to target just the buttons that need to have the scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from **itsgoingdown's** answer. The animation is ignored because the default link event still fires. If you pass the event and also prevent the default, you'll be set. See below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main-navigation a[href^="#"]' ).click(function(event) {

        // Prevent default link action
        event.preventDefault();

        // Grab location to send to
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // Scroll the page, animated
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top  
        }, 700);

    });
});
```

Here is a live JSFiddle to show as well.
https://jsfiddle.net/y3nutj22/5/

Comment: Nope. Still not working. Can you go to http://23.235.212.120/~dairyberries/dairyking/ click on Our Products and watch what transpires? No scrollTo effect.

Comment: @AdamBell - According to your source code, the **event** and **event.preventDefault();** are not present in that code. Starting on the generated line of 413 in "View Source".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the both of you. I finally figured it out and in a sense, you're both right. However, neither of your codes produced the scrollTo effect. While '.main-navigation a[href^="#"]' was partially correct, my issue....and I finally realized it this morning....was I hard coded in the URL's in WordPress' menu feature as a complete URL. So just using '#' wouldn't work. Also, since it's WP, I can't use $'s in the code, Have ot use jQuery, of course.

This is the code that did the trick.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.main-navigation a[href^="http://path.to.url/#"]' ).click(function(){
  jQuery.scrollTo( this.hash, 1000, { easing:'swing' });
  return false;
});
```

with path.to.url representing the actual URL, of course.

Thanks again!